# React build file not loading components in html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Basically, I want to show my react app in a single script tag.
I created a build file with web pack. I don't know how to interpret it.
But it is not displaying anything when I load it into my html file.
Chrome is showing the build file as a source but nothing is displayed on the browser
I also tried to add some js functions in build file manually like:

```
document.getElementById('ex-wid').innerHTML = "TESTING"
```

It is displayed on the page correctly but other react components or images are not added to the div.

html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Embedded Widget App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='ex-wid' ></div>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Webpack config:

```html
const path = require("path");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob
      .sync(
        "build/static/?(js|css|media)/*.?(js|css|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)"
      )
      .map((f) => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        use: ["url-loader?limit=100000"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
};
```

build file:  https://file.io/e8QRWtx00GsB

Comment: What is your folder structure? is `index.html` in the same directory as `bundle.js`?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned above, I'm getting bundle.js if look through source files in chrome files